# index out of bounds c# (I'm trying to add savegame and am using WriteAllLines)

Tags: c#, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to make savegame for a quite simple game, and this is the code I am using right now to write money to a .txt file (NameBox is the textbox you use to write the name of the .txt file):

```
private void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String filename = NameBox.Text;
        if (filename == "")
        {
            filename = "New Save";
        }
        filename += ".txt";
        String[] Money = new String[MainForm.Money];
        Money[MainForm.Money] = MainForm.Money.ToString();
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(filename, Money);
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

However I get an index out of bounds error on whatever line is after

```
Money[MainForm.Money] = MainForm.Money.ToString();
```

I've also tried doing this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MainForm.Money; i++){
    Money[MainForm.Money] = MainForm.Money.ToString();
}
```

But it gives me an error on the closing body (squiggly bracket as I call it)
I have done a savegame before with an array of walls and soldiers saving their sizes and locations using this code (wallList[i].ToString() refers to a method in the wall class that returns all the values):

```
private void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String filename = filenametxt.Text;
        if (filename == "")
        {
            filename = "Level";
        }
        filename += ".txt";
        String[] lines = new String[MainForm.wallList.Count + 
        MainForm.soldierList.Count+1];
        for (int i = 0; i < MainForm.wallList.Count; i++)
        {
            lines[i] = MainForm.wallList[i].ToString();
        }
        lines[MainForm.wallList.Count] = "@";
        for (int i = 0; i < MainForm.soldierList.Count; i++)
        {
            lines[i + MainForm.wallList.Count +1] = 
            MainForm.soldierList[i].ToString();
        }
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(filename, lines);
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

I would very much appreciate if someone could help me! (Please explain to me what each part of the code means, for example explaining that .ToString() converts an int into a string)

Comment: An IndexOutOfBoundsException means that you are attempting to access a part of a collection that doesn't exist. The index is either too high or too low. Imagine your collection as a line of people, you're trying to get person X but there is no person X. A better understanding of this exception will probably make it more clear to you why this is occurring.

Comment: Yes, I know what an index out of bounds exception is, I'm just not sure why it is happening. It happened when I did the savegame for the over game I mentioned, but I managed to fix it by playing around with the code like I did here. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6):

```
String[] Money = new String[MainForm.Money];
```

Here you create the array of size MainForm.Money. Say the value of MainForm.Money is 10.
The array is size 10, meaning there are 10 slots. These are numbered 0-9.

```
Money[MainForm.Money] = MainForm.Money.ToString();
```

Here you do the equivalent of Money[10] when it only has slots up to 9. Thus you go "Out of Bounds" of the array.

Answer (score 2):

#### In short:

Arrays are 0-based so this array access is the problem:

```
Money[MainForm.Money] = ... // MainForm.Money-1 would be okay
```

#### In more detail:

So we have these two lines causing your problem:

```
String[] Money = new String[MainForm.Money];
Money[MainForm.Money] = MainForm.Money.ToString();
```

Assuming that `MoneyForm.Money` is an `int` - let's pretend it is 5000:
In this case you are creating a string array `Money` with 5000 empty slots to store strings in.

In the second line you basically say that you want to write that 5000 as string (so `"5000"`) in the array's 5000th element.

```
Money[5000] = "5000";
```

But when you declare an array with 5000 "slots" you have them **from 0-4999 because arrays are 0-based. That's why 5000 is "out of bounds"**.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are initializing an array with the length of Mainform.Money that starts at 0 up to Mainform.Money - 1, but when you try to set the value of Money[Mainform.Money], you are setting that value outside the defined array.

Comment: Thank you all for the very quick responses! Although I now know what the problem is, can anyone tell me how I can fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are populating the string array `Money` with length equal to the value of `MainForm.Money` the maximum possible index for the array is equal to `MainForm.Money -1` not `MainForm.Money`:

```
    Money[MainForm.Money] = MainForm.Money.ToString(); 
// you should change the index here to be within the range (0 - MainForm.Money -1) based on your requirements
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line below, you initialized the Money to have be an array of x amount of

```
    strings (x = MainForm.Money).
```

Then you tried to access item x + 1 from the line below, which caused the exception. If you want to access the last element of the array, you should call Money[MainForm.Money - 1].

```
    Money[MainForm.Money] = MainForm.Money.ToString();
```